# How to add numbers in an array - Typescript

Tags: typescript, angular9

I want 5 numbers ranging from 1 to 5 (numberOfScreen has value 5 which comes from the API captured in it) to be pushed into the array, but I am getting the below error

core.js:6241 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Find the code snippet below:

```
screens: Array<number>;
numberOfScreen: number;

get screenNumbers(): Number[] {
  for (let i = 1; i <= this.numberOfScreen; i++) {
    this.screens.push(i);
  }
  return this.screens;
}
```

I am new to Typescript so I wanted to understand where I am going wrong.

Comment: `screens: Array<number>;` is not yet initialized.  `screens = [];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize your screens variable with blank array;

```
screens: Array<number> = [];
```